# Convergence of Infinite Series ($\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 3^{\frac{1}{2i-1}}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the best convergence test to use for $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 3^{\frac{1}{2i-1}}$? I want to show that it converges and what it converges to.

Comment: It doesn't converge, for $i$ large the summand is very close to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 3^{\frac{1}{2i-1}} > \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 3^{0} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1 \to \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

$a_i=3^{\frac{1}{2i-1}} \to 1$, as $i \to +\infty$

If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i<+\infty$ then we woof have that $a_i \to 0$ which is not the case.